# Repeat table header in html-pdf library while creating PDF from data in node.js

Tags: node.js, html-pdf, node-html-pdf

I have one scenario in which I have multiple tables to print by creating PDF. For say, I have 4 tables together and the third table is having number of rows resulting in page change. I want to repeat that table's header on the next page also before printing the rows of that specific table. For any table out of 4 tables, if table's data extends to another page, it should repeat the header also for current table on next page. Is that possible in any way?
Any experts, can you please suggest me on this as I am really looking for it.

I am working on node.js to perform this task. Currently using this library-

```
"html-pdf": "3.0.1"
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf?activeTab=readme

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this task perfectly and also with some more advancements in my PDF.
Whosoever is looking for the same, and unable to find any solution, I suggest you to use PdfMake NPM for the same. I have attached playground url of that NPM, where you can test various things and you can start work on your task,.

http://pdfmake.org/playground.html